# Need to ignore leading zeros for digit count function in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, iteration, digit, leading-zero

`.123` is converted to `0.123` as a string so my count comes out at `(0,0,1)` instead of `(0,0,0)`. I need to ignore that leading 0 but **I can't figure out how**.

```
def digit_count(n):
    n=str(int(n))
    even_count=0
    odd_count=0
    zero_count=0
    for i in n:

        if int(i)%10 ==0:
            zero_count +=1
        elif int(i) % 2 ==0:
            even_count += 1 
        elif int(i) %2 !=0:
            odd_count +=1

    return(even_count,odd_count,zero_count)
```

Comment: Can you just multiple the number by 10 before converting it into a string?

Comment: `n.strip("0")`?

Comment: What about `0.00005`?

Comment: multiplying won't work because i only want to count the digits to the left of the decimal

Comment: I've tried n.strip("0") but i can't find the right place to put it to get it to work

Comment: JK n=n.lstrip("0") did the trick. Thank y'all so much :)

Comment: By the way, `odd = total - even`. In other words, you can save yourself a variable counter

Answer (score 0):

One hacky solution:

```
def digit_count(n):

    if isinstance(n, float) and str(n).split('.')[0]=='0':
        return (0,0,0)
    else:
        n=str(int(n))


    even_count=0
    odd_count=0
    zero_count=0
    for i in n:

        if int(i)%10 ==0:
            zero_count +=1
        elif int(i) % 2 ==0:
            even_count += 1 
        elif int(i) %2 !=0:
            odd_count +=1

    return(even_count,odd_count,zero_count)
```

Comment: it needs to only count the digits to the left of the decimal point

Answer (score 0):

```
def digit_count( n ) :
    ## convert number to string
    n = str( int(n))
    ## declare counts
    even_count, zero_count = 0,0

    for i in n :
        i = int(i)            
    ## case when n = 0.1231            
        if len(n) == 1 and i == 0:
            return (0,0,0)
    ## case when n contains 0
        elif i == 0:
            zero_count += 1
    ## case when n contains even
        elif i != 0  and i%2 == 0 :
            even_count += 1            
    return ( even_count, len(n) - even_count- zero_count, zero_count )

digit_count( 123059.9 )
>> (1,4,1)
digit_count( 0.123 )
>> (0,0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this for a python 3 solution?

```py
    def digit_count(n):
        n=list(str(int(n))); #turn into a list array
        if n[-1] == "0":     #get the first item (leading zeroes).
            n[-1] = "";      #delete it.
        n=''.join(n);        #rejoin as a new string.
        even_count = odd_count = zero_count = 0; #I cleaned this up too.
        for i in n:
            if int(i)%10 == 0:
                zero_count += 1
            elif (int(i) % 2 == 0) ^ (int(i) %2 == 0): #I cleaned this up I hope you don't mind.
                even_count += 1
        return(even_count,odd_count,zero_count) 
    print(digit_count(.123));
```